# How do I LINQ nested lists to JSON in Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api that returns Json. My out put looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "NodeID":1252,
      "CASNumber":"1333-86-4",
      "EINECSCode":"215-609-9",
      "EUIndex":"215-609-9",
      "Duty":"No",
      "Prohibited":"No",
      "Unwanted":"No",
      "IsReach":"No",
      "SubstanceName":"Carbon black",
      "GroupName":"Renault Complete",
      "Portion":0.100000
   },
   {  
      "NodeID":1252,
      "CASNumber":"1333-86-4",
      "EINECSCode":"215-609-9",
      "EUIndex":"215-609-9",
      "Duty":"No",
      "Prohibited":"No",
      "Unwanted":"No",
      "IsReach":"No",
      "SubstanceName":"Carbon black",
      "GroupName":"Renault Orange",
      "Portion":0.100000
   }
]
```

I Am trying to create nested Json with an ouptut like this:

```
{  
   "NodeID":1252,
   "CASNumber":"1333-86-4",
   "EINECSCode":"215-609-9",
   "EUIndex":"215-609-9",
   "Duty":"No",
   "Prohibited":"No",
   "Unwanted":"No",
   "IsReach":"No",
   "SubstanceName":"Carbon black",
   "GroupName":[  
      {  
         "name":"Renault Complete"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Renault Orange"
      }
   ],
   "Portion":0.100000
}
```

This is my class:

```
public class BasicSubstances
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string CASNumber { get; set; }
    public string EINECSCode { get; set; }
    public string EUIndex { get; set; }
    public string Duty { get; set; }
    public string Prohibited { get; set; }
    public string Unwanted { get; set; }
    public string IsReach { get; set; }
    public string SubstanceName { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public decimal ?Portion { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public List<BasicSubstances> GetBasicSubstance(string partNumber,  string version, int nodeID, int parentID )
{
    IMDSDataContext dc = new IMDSDataContext();
    List<BasicSubstances> results = new List<BasicSubstances>();

    foreach (spGetBasicSubstanceResult part in dc.spGetBasicSubstance( partNumber, version, nodeID, parentID))
    {
        results.Add(new BasicSubstances()
            {
                NodeID = part.NodeID,
                CASNumber = part.CASNumber,
                EINECSCode = part.EINECSCode,
                EUIndex = part.EINECSCode,
                Duty = part.Duty,
                Prohibited = part.Prohibited,
                Unwanted = part.Unwanted,
                IsReach = part.ISReach,
                SubstanceName = part.SynonymName,
                GroupName = part.GroupName,
                Portion = part.Portion

            });

    }
    return results;
}
```

My Json looks like the first output, I need it to look like the second output.
I totally lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How you can be sure that all properties except `GroupName` will have the same values?

Comment: They will always have the same value. In my stored procedure its only one record, i joined a table to get a multiple list of group names.

Comment: Type of GroupName should be `public List<Sometime> GroupName { get; set; }`? You cannot create json array out of string. You need to do something here `GroupName = part.GroupName,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can try the following:

**Your models:**

```
public class BasicSubstanceViewModel 
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string CASNumber { get; set; }
    public string EINECSCode { get; set; }
    public string EUIndex { get; set; }
    public string Duty { get; set; }
    public string Prohibited { get; set; }
    public string Unwanted { get; set; }
    public string IsReach { get; set; }
    public string SubstanceName { get; set; }
    public List<GroupName> GroupName { get; set; }
    public decimal ?Portion { get; set; }
}

public class GroupName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Your method:**

```
public BasicSubstanceViewModel GetBasicSubstance(string partNumber,  string version, int nodeID, int parentID )
{
    IMDSDataContext dc = new IMDSDataContext();
    var spResult = dc.spGetBasicSubstance( partNumber, version, nodeID, parentID).ToList();

    if(!spResult.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    var firstPart = spResult[0];

    var result = new BasicSubstanceViewModel
    {
        NodeID = firstPart.NodeID,
        CASNumber = firstPart.CASNumber,
        EINECSCode = firstPart.EINECSCode,
        EUIndex = firstPart.EINECSCode,
        Duty = firstPart.Duty,
        Prohibited = firstPart.Prohibited,
        Unwanted = firstPart.Unwanted,
        IsReach = firstPart.ISReach,
        SubstanceName = firstPart.SynonymName,
        GroupName = spResult.Select(p => new GroupName { Name = p.GroupName }).ToList(),
        Portion = firstPart.Portion
    };

    return result;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: var firstPart = spResult[0]; throws an error:  Error 14 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<IMDSEbs.Models.spGetBasicSubstanceResult>'

Comment: Work perfect, Needs a SemiColon after:  Portion = firstPart.Portion
    };. It would not let me edit.   Thanks

Comment: I left out a detail, I hope you are willing to help me with this. Turns out I needed SubstanceName to be nested also. When i change the code to accommodate that. i get duplicates for both SubstanceName and GroupName.

Comment: You just need to modify your `ViewModel` to accommodate one more collection. You even can use the same nested model/class.

Comment: I did that but now i get duplicate values.

Comment: SubstanceName = spResult.Select(s => new SubstanceName { SubName = s.SynonymName }).ToList(),
                GroupName = spResult.Select(p => new GroupName { Name = p.GroupName }).ToList(),

Comment: public List <SubstanceName> SubstanceName { get; set; }

Comment: public class  SubstanceName
    {
        public string SubName { get; set; }
    }